# First row in D3 DataTable is sorted incorrectly - D3/DC/Crossfilter

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have some basic d3/dc/crossfilter code that is used to render a datatable.  The datatable should be sorted by column N (which is simply the row number).  Whenever the table is rendered in the browser, some random row is the top row, and then in the second row the highest row is displayed, followed by the next highest as is appropriate.  I initially thought this error might be due to chrome's sort being unsafe, but given the fact that all the values of column N are unique, this shouldnt be an issue.

my code:

```
function makeGraphs(error, trades) {

     trades.forEach(function(d) {
         d['N'] = +d['N'] 
})  


var tradeTable = dc.dataTable("#dc-table-graph");

var trades = crossfilter(trades);

var NDimension = trades.dimension(function (d) {
    return d['N']});


tradeTable.width(960).height(800)
.dimension(NDimension)
.group(function(d) { return "trades"
})
.size(110)
.columns([
function(d) { return d.N; },
function(d) { return d['Profit']; },
])
.sortBy(function(d){ return -d.N; })
.order(d3.descending)
dc.renderAll();
 };
```

my output looks as follows

```
N     Profit
54     .56
107    .36
106     .33
105     .25
104     .21
all the way down to N=1
```

Obviously the first row shouldn't be 54, yet for some reason it is.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: That's weird. Could you create a working example of the problem please? JSfiddle or similar sites work well for this.

Comment: It looks like they are still sorted as strings despite the forEach at the top. I wonder if the code is getting executed in the order shown here.

Comment: ^ it is.  and strangely it works in internet explorer, but not chrome

Answer (score 0):

I built a working example of this, but am unable to recreate the problem: http://bl.ocks.org/esjewett/5d84984dd8436542bb33

Please feel free to fork the block at http://blockbuilder.org/esjewett/5d84984dd8436542bb33 and try to recreate the problem for us.

I would note that

```
trades.forEach(function(d) {
  d['N'] = +d['N'] 
})
```

doesn't seem to me to do anything with regards to sorting because in the sort it is `-d.N`, which casts to a number anyway.